# How do I separate the time and date in SQL navigator?

Tags: oracle, date

I am trying to separate the time and date in one column to be independent off each other. I am new at writing scripts

this is my query:

```sql
select
    *
from
    [tablename]
where
    to_date([column_name]) in ( '15-Jun-2021', '16-Jun-2021' )
    and
    to_char([column_name],'dd-Mon-yyyy HH:MM:ss') < '15-Jun-2021 19:54:30'
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us, we can read lowercase letters perfectly fine. Thank you.

Comment: Also, are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? `TO_DATE` is not a T-SQL function.

Comment: `to_char()` and `to_date()` are Oracle syntax. This code won't run on Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: I am using oracle pls. sorry

Comment: Your query will run slowly because it isn't SARGable. You don't need to use `to_char` to compare dates.

Comment: Please post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your `[tablename]`. We need to know the exact data-types of your columns.

Comment: This will definitely work the way you would expect. If you convert something to char, it will be compared in **alphabetical** order. `to_char([column_name],'dd-Mon-yyyy HH:MM:ss') < '15-Jun-2021 19:54:30'`.

Comment: if your [column_name] is of data type DATE, then you need not _and should not_ be converting it to a character string (to_char) for comparisons.  And if it is _not_ of data type DATE, then you have a fundamental design flaw in your table.   Please read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you put it, it would be

```
select *
from your_table
where date_column >= date '2021-06-15'
  and date_column < to_date('15.06.2021 19:54:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

because

- `date_column` should be of `date` datatype. If it isn't, you'll have problems of many kinds in the future. Therefore,

  - don't `to_date` it, it is already a date
  - don't `to_char` it either, because you'd be comparing *strings* and get unexpected result. Use that function when you want to *nicely* display the result
- the second condition you wrote makes the first one *questionable*. If `date_column` is less than value you wrote, then you can omit `date '2021-06-16'` from the first condition because you won't get any rows for that date anyway
- date literal (`date '2021-06-15'`) sets time to *midnight*, so condition I wrote *should* return rows you want

  ```
  SQL> select date '2021-06-15' first,
    2         to_date('15.06.2021 19:54:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') second
    3  from dual;

  FIRST               SECOND
  ------------------- -------------------
  15.06.2021 00:00:00 15.06.2021 19:54:30

  SQL>
  ```